# Logged out after subscription is destroyed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, stripe-payments

I have created a subscription Service using Stripe. Everything works, however, when I destroy/create a subscription and the User is updated by using after_create or after_destroy in the subscription model, it logs the current user out.

I have a basic authentication system just like in Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-in-sign-out?version=3.2#sec-remember_me). Basically, a remember token is stored in a cookie.

**My after_create & after_destroy in my Subscription Model calls save in my User Model which of course fires save callbacks. Which means that saving a user will always invalidate the remember token. Is there a work around so that this does not happen?**

Looking at the Logs, you can see that the remember_token that is being generated after_destroy, gets called and then becomes invalid.

MODELS

```
SUBSCRIPTION MODEL

class Subscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :paypal_customer_token, :paypal_recurring_profile_token, :plan_id, :name,
                  :user_id, :email, :paypal_payment_token, :stripe_customer_token, 
                  :stripe_card_token

  attr_accessor :paypal_payment_token, :stripe_card_token

  belongs_to :plan
  belongs_to :user

  ###used to update the user
  after_create  do

    ###something happens when the user is updated that logs him out.
    user.update_attribute(:subscribed, true) unless self.user.subscribed
  end

  after_destroy do
    user.update_attribute(:subscribed, false) if user.subscribed == true
  end


end


USER MODEL

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :subscribed

  has_secure_password

  ###This updates my remember_token when the subscription model updates the User
  before_save :create_remember_token

  has_one :subscription, :dependent => :destroy

  private

    def create_remember_token
      self.remember_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end

end
```

CONTROLLER

```
class SubscriptionsController < ApplicationController

  respond_to :html, :js

  def create
    @subscription = Subscription.new(params[:subscription])
    if @subscription.save_with_payment
      redirect_to @subscription, :success => "Thank you for subscribing!"
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @subscription = current_user.subscription
    @subscription.cancel_monthly_subscription
    if current_user.subscription.destroy
      flash[:success] = 'Your Subscription was Succesfully Cancelled.'
      redirect_to root_path
    end
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to (root_path), notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:update, :edit, :account]
  before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update, :account]

  respond_to :html, :js

  def edit
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def account
    @title = "Account"
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      error_messages = @user.errors.messages
      @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
      @user.errors.messages.merge!(error_messages)
      if URI(request.referer).path == edit_user_path 
        render 'edit'
      else
        render 'account'
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def signed_in_user
      unless signed_in?
        store_location
        redirect_to (root_path), notice: "Please sign in."
      end
    end

    def correct_user
      @user = User.find_by_username(params[:id])
      redirect_to(root_path) unless current_user?(@user)
    end

end
```

LOGS

```
###Is there a reason why the remember token changes at some point, 
could that be the problem?

Processing by SubscriptionsController#destroy as HTML

Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"aSIR3K3STsdC1vfOKqLZ0Hae28wkbk8TD1Eab5LXzHY=", "id"=>"29"}
User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '-jhzlnlPqy6-okkbZRoyrg' LIMIT 1

Subscription Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "subscriptions".* FROM "subscriptions" 
WHERE "subscriptions"."user_id" = 1 LIMIT 1

Subscription Exists (0.6ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "subscriptions" 
WHERE ("subscriptions"."user_id" = 1 AND "subscriptions"."id" != 29) LIMIT 1

(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "subscriptions" WHERE "subscriptions"."id" = $1  [["id", 29]]
User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1

 (1.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "subscribed" = 'f', 
"remember_token" = 'WedwAYLkPPUGrwlHLECDTA', "updated_at" = '2014-03-01 00:43:24.696602' 
WHERE "users"."id" = 1

[paperclip] Saving attachments.
  PgSearch::Document Load (1.8ms)  SELECT "pg_search_documents".* 
  FROM "pg_search_documents" WHERE "pg_search_documents"."searchable_id" = 1 
  AND "pg_search_documents"."searchable_type" = 'User' LIMIT 1
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  (1.0ms)  COMMIT

Redirected to http://0.0.0.0:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 2307ms (ActiveRecord: 8.5ms)



Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-28 16:43:24 -0800
Processing by StaticPagesController#home as HTML

  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '-jhzlnlPqy6-okkbZRoyrg' LIMIT 1

  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '-jhzlnlPqy6-okkbZRoyrg' LIMIT 1

  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered shared/_error_messages.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered sessions/_new.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Rendered static_pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (18.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_shim.html.erb (0.1ms)

  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '-jhzlnlPqy6-okkbZRoyrg' LIMIT 1

  Rendered layouts/_navigation_links.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navigation.html.erb (4.1ms)

  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
  WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '-jhzlnlPqy6-okkbZRoyrg' LIMIT 1

  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (3.5ms)
  Completed 200 OK in 161ms (Views: 157.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.8ms)
```

Comment: Are you using any gems to manage your authentication?

Comment: no, i did it from scratch using michael hartl's rails tutorial. i have updated my code with the user model.

Comment: If you wrote the authentication yourself, it's very hard for anyone to tell you why it's signing out.  If you were using something like devise others could give input.  I suggest you start debugging your authentication code to try and establish why you are not logged in anymore (your app responds with 302 redirect).

Comment: would it have to do with after_save in my user model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In reference to `@Pierre Pretorius`'s comment, the reason the sign out occurs is beacuse you're replacing the `remember token`, or changing the data as to create a mismatch between your session & persistent data

I've not read the Hartl tutorial, but if your app signs out the user if the `remember_token` is changed, you need to ensure it remains the same:

---

[**Conditional callbacks**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#conditional-callbacks)

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    before_save :create_remember_token, unless: :subscription?

    def subscription?
         subscribed == true?
         #could just use "subscribed"
    end
end
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you! :), I am also thinking of using an update_column method instead because it skips callbacks according to this. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-update_column